# Why named variable calls are resolved to T&& instead of const T&?

Tags: c++, c++11

As the title says, why named variables calls are resolved to `T&&` instead of `const T&` functions?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T&& v)
{
    std::cout << "void f(T&& v)" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void f(const T& v)
{
    std::cout << "void f(const T& v)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    f(1);
    f(i);
}
```

In this case both calls are resolved to first version of `f()`, even if `i` is named. One solution would be to add also:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& v)
{
    std::cout << "void f(T& v)" << std::endl;
}
```

or to change first version to:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_reference<T>::value, void>::type f(T&& v)
{
    std::cout << "void f(T&& v)" << std::endl;
}
```

but I want to understand the reasons behind this decision.

Comment: *Note:* The partial ordering rules between two function templates ("more specialized than") are only used if no conversion sequence for the argument -> parameter conversion is *better* for the two specializations of the function templates.

Comment: Ah, you have run into this: **[The Universal Reference/Overloading Collision Conundrum](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5swP3dr190)**. In short: don't overload on universal references; it will give you very counterintuitive results... :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The deduction is `T = int &`, which means `f(T &&) == f(int &)`. The overload resolution rules ([over.ics.rank/13.3.3.2]) say that this is is a strictly better match than `f(int const &)`. Both are classified as an "exact match" (binding a value to a reference), but the less CV-qualified reference is preferred.

Comment: *Pedantic remark:* Both "conversions" have the same rank, pretty much any direct reference binding (= no temporary created) but binding a derived class to a base class reference is an Exact Match. There's a special disambiguation rule for `T const&` vs. `T&` in [over.ics.rank]/3

Comment: @dyp: Thanks a lot, I reworded.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this: "the less CV-qualified reference is preferred."

Comment: @Felics: Yeah, please do read the overload resolution rules if you have an hour or eight to spare. They comprise 30 pages of language standardese, but they're worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

A less standardese-encumbered answer would be to recognise that in the declaration:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& v)
```

Because `T` is a deduced type, `T&& v` is what Scott Meyers calls a [*universal reference*](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), which can bind to both rvalues and lvalues.  `T` can be deduced to be a reference type, so you are actually calling `f<int&>(int& && v)`, at which point the reference-collapsing rules come into effect, making the nominal signature of this function `f<int&>(int& v)` which, as the previous answer noted, is a better match for a non-const `int` argument.

In Meyers' upcoming [*Effective Modern C++*](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/book-report-new-title-new-toc-new.html) he has the following items:

- Item 30: Pass and return rvalue references via std::move, universal references via std::forward.
- Item 31: Avoid overloading on universal references.

Item 31 tells you what not to do. Item 30 suggests what you could do instead, write only one overload of `f`, and perfectly forward `v` with `std::forward`:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& v)
{
    std::cout << "void f(T&& v)" << std::endl;

    if (std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(v)>::value)
        std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "v = " << std::forward<T>(v) << std::endl;
}
```